# text not shown in rechart react js with bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, recharts

I am using the Recharts library to create an admin dashboard, and I need to create a horizontal bar chart similar to the one shown in the screenshot. I have attempted to implement the example provided in the following code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-horizontal-bar-with-dual-y-axis-25v91?file=/src/index.js

During my implementation, I encountered several errors. However, one specific issue is that the text on the left-hand side of the chart is not displaying correctly. When I inspected the element and manually adjusted the text size, it appeared as shown in the following screenshot:

https://app.screencast.com/zOpmhCaGsYpUw

I would appreciate it if you could help me identify the exact problem causing this issue. Thank you.

My code is :

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
   ResponsiveContainer,
   BarChart,
   Bar,
   XAxis,
   YAxis,
   Cell,
   Text
} from "recharts";

const blues = [
   ["#2b65f0"],
   ["#2b65f0", "#2b65f0"],
   ["#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0"],
   ["#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0"],
   ["#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0", "#2b65f0"]
];

const getColor = (length, index) => {
   if (length <= blues.length) {
      return blues[length - 1][index];
   }

   return blues[blues.length - 1][index % blues.length];
};

const YAxisLeftTick = ({ y, payload: { value } }) => {
   return (
      <Text x={0} y={y} textAnchor="start" verticalAnchor="middle" scaleToFit>
         {value}
      </Text>
   );
};

let ctx;

export const measureText14HelveticaNeue = text => {
   if (!ctx) {
      ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
      ctx.font = "14px 'Helvetica Neue";
   }

   return ctx.measureText(text).width;
};

const BAR_AXIS_SPACE = 10;

const ScreenResolutionStat = ({ data, yKey, xKey, title }) => {
   const maxTextWidth = useMemo(
      () =>
         data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            const value = cur[yKey];
            const width = measureText14HelveticaNeue(value.toLocaleString());
            if (width > acc) {
               return width;
            }
            return acc;
         }, 0),
      [data, yKey]
   );

   return (
      <>
         <h4 className="mb-20">{title}</h4>
         <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={50 * data.length} debounce={50}>
            <BarChart
               data={data}
               minAngle
               layout="vertical"
               margin={{ left: 10, right: maxTextWidth + (BAR_AXIS_SPACE - 8) }}
            >
               <XAxis hide axisLine={true} type="number" />
               <YAxis
                  yAxisId={0}
                  dataKey={xKey}
                  type="category"
                  axisLine={true}
                  tickLine={true}
                  tick={YAxisLeftTick}
               />
               <YAxis
                  orientation="right"
                  yAxisId={1}
                  dataKey={yKey}
                  type="category"
                  axisLine={false}
                  tickLine={false}
                  tickFormatter={value => value.toLocaleString()}
                  mirror
                  tick={{
                     transform: `translate(${maxTextWidth + BAR_AXIS_SPACE}, 0)`
                  }}
               />
               <Bar dataKey={yKey} minPointSize={2} barSize={32}>
                  {data.map((d, idx) => {
                     return <Cell key={d[xKey]} fill={getColor(data.length, idx)} />;
                  })}
               </Bar>
            </BarChart>
         </ResponsiveContainer>
      </>
   );
};
YAxisLeftTick.propTypes = {
   y: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
   payload: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
// Prop types
ScreenResolutionStat.propTypes = {
   data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
   yKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   xKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ScreenResolutionStat;
```